# Get an array of objects from a Razor page with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I am developing an asp.net core web app.
I am sending data from a razor page to getJson script to display a chart on the page.
When I'm sending an array of anonymous classes, getJson receives data. When I'm sending an array of custom class, getJson receives an array of empty objects that have no properties.

Received OK:

```
            var anonymousarray = new[]
                {
                    new {name = "first", value = 3 },
                    new {name = "second", value = 6 },
                    new {name = "third", value = 1 },
                };
```

Received as an array of empty objects:

```
            Test[] testarray = new []
            {
                new Test {name = "first", value = 3},
                new Test {name = "second", value = 6},
                new Test {name = "third", value = 1}
            };
```

Test class:

```
    public class Test
    {
        public int value;
        public string name;
    }
```

Handler on Razor page:

```
        public JsonResult OnGetData()
        {
            Test[] testarray= new[]
            {
                new Test {name = "first", value = 3},
                new Test {name = "second", value = 6},
                new Test {name = "third", value = 1}
            };
            
            return new JsonResult(testarray);
        }
```

Razor page script:

```
@section scripts{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d');
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON(`?handler=Data`, (data) => {
                var labels = [];
                var dataresults = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    labels.push(item.name);
                    dataresults.push(item.value);
                });
                console.log(labels)
                console.log(dataresults)
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Results',
                            data: dataresults,
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            y: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Please help me to send an array/list of my custom classes to getJson script. I spent many hours reading articles and posts but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm sending an array of anonymous classes, getJson receives data. When I'm sending an array of custom class, getJson receives an array of empty objects that have no properties.

Please try to modify your `Test` class to define `value` and `name` as property with `get` and `set` accessor, like below.

```
 public class Test
    {
        public int value {get;set;};
        public string name {get;set;};
    }
```

From this doc about ["Serialization behavior"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#serialization-behavior), you can find:

> - Fields are ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! I was pulling my hair out.